# Changing The base time unit displayed on prometheus endpoint

Tags: micrometer, spring-micrometer

Before switching to Micrometer, we were leveraging Prometheus in several of our Spring Boot applications. Prometheus showed all our timings in milliseconds. Now that we have switched to Micrometer, All the timer and `@Timed` metrics are all in seconds. I was able to modify the max metric by extending the `PrometheusMeterRegistry` and overriding `getBaseTimeUnit` the but the sum metric of the `Timer` does not respect the same override.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the [very concerns covered by a Prometheus core committer](https://www.robustperception.io/who-wants-seconds).

I would recommend against trying to adjust it to milliseconds since it would be fighting the system. If you are using Grafana to display your dashboards, then it will handle the unit regardless of the underlying implementation.

Comment: Normally I would agree to your answer. But with the previous prometheus endpoint everything was in milliseconds. Since some applications are still using the old prometheus endpoints the grafana dashboards are a nightmare to handle. It would be nice if I could just keep the base time unit that was already set by the system.